# Magento migration 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

We are actually upgrade our version magento (1.7 to 1.9) but we have an issue when we try to use this function :

```
->addFieldToFilter('CHAR_LENGTH(review)', array('gteq' => 20))
```

This work in magento 1.7 but doesn't in 1.9.
Do you have solution ? 
Here the complet request :

```
$collection = $content_database->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect(array('firstname', 'lastname', 'review_date', 'review', 'rate'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('rate', array('gteq' => $this->_rating))
        ->addFieldToFilter('CHAR_LENGTH(review)', array('gteq' => 20))
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())
        ->setOrder("review_date", "desc")
        ->setPageSize($size);

    return $collection;
```

Here is the error message :

'CHAR_LENGTH(review)' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `upecom_reviews` AS `main_table` WHERE (`rate` >= 4) AND (`CHAR_LENGTH(review)` >= 20) AND (`store_id` = '1')'

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in magento 1.9 you can't use anymore sql function in the first parameter.
 So you should use regex like this :

```
$collection = $content_database->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect(array('firstname', 'lastname', 'review_date', 'review', 'rate'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('rate', array('gteq' => $this->_rating))
            ->addFieldToFilter("review", array('regexp' => '^.{20,}$'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())
            ->setOrder("review_date", "desc")
            ->setPageSize($size);
```

Good luck Cem:)